# html, странное поведение блока при адаптиве при использовании отрицательных margin

Tags: html, css

Не могу никак решить проблему, использовал отрицательные margin для flex контейнера и padding для flex элементов чтобы сделать расстояние между ними, но при уменьшении окна просмотра появляется горизонтальное окно прокрутки и блок содержащий колонки становится меньше чем его содержимое

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="services">
                <div class="services__container container">
                    <div class="services__header decor-title">
                        <div class="decor-title__title title">
                            <div class="title__item">Популярные</div>
                            <h2 class="title__main title__main_w">Лоты на аукцион</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="decor-title__decor decor-block">
                            <div class="decor-block__decor">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="decor-block__icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="decor-block__decor decor-block__decor_r">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services__body">
                        <div class="services__row">
                            <div class="services__column">
                                <div class="services__item item-services">
                                    <div class="item-services__icon">
                                        <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                                    <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="services__column">
                                <div class="services__item item-services">
                                    <div class="item-services__icon">
                                        <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                                    <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="services__column">
                                <div class="services__item item-services">
                                    <div class="item-services__icon">
                                        <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                                    <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    max-width: 970px;

    
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;

}
html {
}

.services {
    padding: 40px 0 60px;
    background-color: #1c242a;
    &__container {}
    &__header {
        margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    }
    &__body {}
    &__row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 0 -50px;
    }
    &__column {
        padding: 0 50px;
        flex: 0 1 33.333%;


        margin: 0 0 40px;

    }
    @media(max-width: 980px) {
        &__column {
            flex: 0 1 50%;
        }         
    }
    @media(max-width: 650px) {
        &__column {
            flex: 0 1 100%;
        }
    }

    &__item {
        
    }
}
.item-services {
    height: 100%;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;

    color: #fff;
    &__icon {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        img {
            height: 165px;
            width: 165px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }
    
    &__title {
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;

        font-size: 1.25rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    &__text {
        color: goldenrod;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1 1 auto;


        margin: 0 0 20px 0;

    }
    &__link {
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 0.0625em;

        position: relative;

        span {
            padding: 0 10px 0;

            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;

            background: #1c242a;
        }

        &::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;

            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            
            background-color: goldenrod;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому-что нельзя давать -50px; при сужении margin использует внешние отступы, а значит окно равно "100% + 50px * 2".
В общем используйте "display: grid" для формирования блоков. Это вас избавит от вычисления разницы ширины относительно отступам.
Сейчас такое время, когда уже не правильно отступы делать через margin
Также скину ссылку посмотреть как это можно сделать и на "display: flex"
[Красивое расположение элементов через flex и grid контейнеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499826/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-flex-%d0%b8-grid-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b)

```css
.services {
  padding: 40px 0 60px;
  background-color: #1c242a;
}
.services__header {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.services__row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 50px;
}
.services__column {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
}
@media(max-width: 980px) {
  .services__row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media(max-width: 650px) {
  .services__row {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="services">
      <div class="services__container container">
          <div class="services__header decor-title">
              <div class="decor-title__title title">
                  <div class="title__item">Популярные</div>
                  <h2 class="title__main title__main_w">Лоты на аукцион</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="decor-title__decor decor-block">
                  <div class="decor-block__decor">
                      <span></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="decor-block__icon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="decor-block__decor decor-block__decor_r">
                      <span></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services__body">
              <div class="services__row">
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services__column">
                      <div class="services__item item-services">
                          <div class="item-services__icon">
                              <img src="img/human.jpg" alt="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item-services__title">Экспертная оценка</div>
                          <div class="item-services__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla?</div>
                          <a href="#" class="item-services__link"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: В таком случае невозможно будет сделать адекватный перенос элементов grid-а на новую строку с сохранением нужной ширины элемента!?

Comment: А вы результат посмотрите, там две строки, я специально добавил ещё 3 строки, что бы наглядно показать.

Comment: grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; - это количество блоков в строке, если больше трёх, значит перенос на следующую строку. В адаптиве, когда нужно 2 блока на строку пишете - grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;. Или можно писать проще grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); - это значит повторить 3 раза по 1fr

Comment: ну так оно не переносится на новую строку при уменьшении окна просмотра как у моего варианта.

Comment: Так Медиа запросы не сделаны же. Сейчас сделаю

Comment: @Alegro вот просто медиа прописываете новые данные и всё.

Comment: Про медиа я понял спасибо не стоит делать, я учусь делать кроме адаптива ещё и резиновую верстку, не знаю ее используют сейчас или нет, но с grid-ами резиновость не выходит,

Comment: Как не выходит, когда выходит. Я вам вот показал сейчас. Вам даже ширину не надо давать блокам. grid-template-columns сам им даст нужную ширину.

Comment: а точно да понял, тут благодаря 1fr и выходит у grid резиновость, только нужно задавать медиа запросы, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, стрелочку вверх можно нажимать, когда вам помогли - это мотивирует нас помогать вам лучше)